# What does -IV0 version postfix mean?

Tags: apache-kafka

We have Apache Kafka 0.10.2.0 deployed in the three-nodes Azure cluster. We didn't specify `log.message.format.version` option in the `server.properties` file so we expect that it should be Kafka version (i.e. `0.10.2.0`).

But when trying to perform Kafka brokers rolling upgrade we've noticed that `log.message.format.version=0.10.2.0-IV0` in the server log.

According to the [Kafka upgrade guide](https://kafka.apache.org/0100/documentation.html#upgrade) **it seems** that `log.message.format.version` is always **exactly same as Kafka version itself** (if not overridden by `server.properties` configuration, of course).

1. What does the `-IV0` version number postfix mean?
2. Why `log.message.format.version` default differs from the Kafka version?

Answer (score 2):

Basically, `IV0`, `IV1`, `IV2` etc. is a protocol version inside a Kafka version. A particular Kafka version can have multiple protocol changes while it's being developed.

> Since the api protocol may change more than once within the same
>   release and to facilitate people deploying code from trunk, we have
>   the concept of internal versions (first introduced during the 0.10.0
>   development cycle). For example, the first time we introduce a version
>   change in a release, say 0.10.0, we will add a config value
>   "0.10.0-IV0" and a corresponding case object KAFKA_0_10_0-IV0. We will
>   also add a config value "0.10.0" that will be mapped to the latest
>   internal version object, which is KAFKA_0_10_0-IV0. When we change the
>   protocol a second time while developing 0.10.0, we will add a new
>   config value "0.10.0-IV1" and a corresponding case object
>   KAFKA_0_10_0-IV1. We will change the config value "0.10.0" to map to
>   the latest internal version object KAFKA_0_10_0-IV1. The config value
>   of "0.10.0-IV0" is still mapped to KAFKA_0_10_0-IV0. This way, if
>   people are deploying from trunk, they can use "0.10.0-IV0" and
>   "0.10.0-IV1" to upgrade one internal version at a time. For most
>   people who just want to use released version, they can use "0.10.0"
>   when upgrading to the 0.10.0 release.

(From the Kafka source code: https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/c216adb4bbf8306977380a1ec371380e30137765/core/src/main/scala/kafka/api/ApiVersion.scala#L30)

Comment: Okay so during rolling upgrade I need to fix `log.message.format.version` to current Kafka version. Does it mean that I must use internal versioning format for that or could it be used as common version format, e.g. `0.10.2.0` (what should be something like alias for `0.10.2.0-IV0`)?

Comment: @zbynour from the answer I guess it's OK to use the plain/common version as it says: `For most people who just want to use released version, they can use "0.10.0" when upgrading to the 0.10.0 release.`